# Package linux-headers not found by aptitude but installed and in use by system?

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, virtualbox

I experience anissue that I don't understand what's happening. Let's see my commands :

```
root@cms:~# sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree
  Reading state information... Done
  virtualbox-5.1 is already the newest version.
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

root@cms:~# /etc/init.d/vboxdrv status
  VirtualBox kernel module is not loaded.

root@cms:~# /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
  vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
  vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
  This system is not currently set up to build kernel modules (system extensions).
  Running the following commands should set the system up correctly:
  apt-get install linux-headers-3.2.0-23-virtual
  (The last command may fail if your system is not fully updated.)
  apt-get install linux-headers-virtual
  vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.

root@cms:~# apt-get install linux-headers-3.2.0-23-virtual
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree
  Reading state information... Done
  E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.2.0-23-virtual
  E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.2.0-23-virtual'

root@cms:~# apt-get install linux-headers-virtual
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree
  Reading state information... Done
  linux-headers-virtual is already the newest version.
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So, I don't understand because virtualbox says I need the linux-headers-3.2.0.23-virtual and Linux says it's allready installed on the system.

If I list headers in /boot/ I have only 3.2.0.23 files.

I'm on Ubnutu 14.04.5 LTS (upgraded a few weeks ago from 12.04 LTS).

**EDIT 1**

```
root@cms:~# apt-cache policy linux-headers-virtual
  linux-headers-virtual:
  Installed: 3.13.0.129.138
  Candidate: 3.13.0.129.138
  Version table:
  *** 3.13.0.129.138 0
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 3.13.0.24.28 0
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

**EDIT 2**

```
root@cms:/tmp# apt-cache policy linux-virtual linux-image-virtual linux-generic linux-image-generic
  linux-virtual:
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: 3.13.0.129.138
    Version table:
      3.13.0.129.138 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
      3.13.0.24.28 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
  linux-image-virtual:
    Installed: 3.13.0.129.138
    Candidate: 3.13.0.129.138
    Version table:
      *** 3.13.0.129.138 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
      3.13.0.24.28 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
  linux-generic:
    Installed: 3.13.0.129.138
    Candidate: 3.13.0.129.138
    Version table:
      *** 3.13.0.129.138 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
      3.13.0.24.28 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
  linux-image-generic:
    Installed: 3.13.0.129.138
    Candidate: 3.13.0.129.138
    Version table:
      *** 3.13.0.129.138 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages  
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
      3.13.0.24.28 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before? If no, can you do that and try again? Also, what does `apt-cache policy linux-headers-virtual` say?

Comment: Of course... update and upgrade. I eddited with cache policy. wll cache gives 3.13, strange !?

Comment: If I was you, I'd rather to uninstall this Virtualbox apt-version and install [directly download .deb file from Oracle VM](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads). Almost everytime I try to `apt install virtualbox`, I've got headache!

Comment: Can you add your `uname -r` and `apt-cache policy linux-virtual linux-image-virtual linux-generic linux-image-generic`?

Comment: Same issue with download manually from Oracle website and `dpkg -i` @Redbob !
@ByteCommander I added this command to my question.

Comment: VBox wants 3.2 you have 3.13.   Im not sure but it suggests to me that you have a different kernel. (3.2 instead of 3.13)

Comment: But when I run `ls` on /boot/ I get 3.2 not 3.13 !? `abi-3.2.0-23-virtual  config-3.2.0-23-virtual  grub  initrd.img-3.2.0-23-virtual  System.map-3.2.0-23-virtual  vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-virtual
`

Comment: exactly you have kernel 3.2, you need the virtual headers for 3.2 not 3.13 which is appearently the latest version. try using `aptitude` to find the right header package, they are under the heading of Kernel I believe

Comment: I don't understand how to use aptitude. can I manually install it from https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/security/linux-headers-3.2.0-126-virtual ? This is for precise, not trusty :( Or dist-upgrade to precise, maybe, but not ready to migrate to php7 with some websites running on the VM.